# How can I hide a console window, but view it when needed?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-10

I have a Python script that runs 24/7. The script prints debug info in the console. So I would like to hide the console window, but view it if need be.

I know I have the option to rename the file to .pyw, but then there is no way I can view the console... that I'm aware of.

Comment: Minimize the console after running the script? :P Jokes apart.. Why to print the content on console instead of writing it to a file?

Comment: Create a shortcut to the script, and set it to start minimized.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri - No particular reason. I suppose that could be a good solution.

Comment: Use .pyw and allocate a console on demand, and then hide the window when you don't need it anymore. Every Windows process can attach to a console. A console application just has a flag in the PE header that tells Windows to inherit or allocate a console automatically.

Comment: Call [`AllocConsole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944) and then open "CONIN$" as `sys.stdin` and "CONOUT$" as `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`. Hide it via [`GetConsoleWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683175) and [`ShowWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548). Free it, if it's no longer needed, via [`FreeConsole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683150) (but first flush and close `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`).